WPF DataGrid DataGridTemplateColumn Click once to enter the edit state
I have used DataGridTemplateColumn, but it doesn't enter edit mode with a single click like DataGridTextColumn does. How can I implement this feature?
By default, the DataGridTextColumn is only a double click to enter the edit state, I used MaterialDesignInXAML and it can click to enter the edit state, but the DataGridTemplateColumn does not.
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="200" Header="{localization:Localize param_lab_pressurerange}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnStyle}" Text="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox
                Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnEditingStyle}"
                Text="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

